# How to stop error 400 when URL contains a percent % symbol? (Apache)

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

Is there a simple way to prevent a server from returning an error 400 (bad request) when a URL is requested containing a percent % symbol?

Many major sites have this same problem, for example: http://twitter.com/% or http://bing.com/%

But other sites have fixed this and return a custom error page instead, rather than the standard server response, such as: http://facebook.com/% or http://google.com/%

Is there a simple, single way to escape a single character % symbol from returning a 400 error, but instead, returning a 404 error using a custom error document using mod_rewrite or similar in Apache?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to allow % in the url?

Comment: Not really. The best way to handle a % in a URL is to do what @arnaud576875 suggested. Have the 'error 400' page check for a % in the URL on the server and then redirect to another page (or 404 page) as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simple, single way to escape a single character % symbol from returning a 400 error

Yes, you have to urlencode any characters you put in a url, if they are not expected to have a special meaning.

For example in PHP:

```
$string = urlencode('%');
```

FYI `%` is encoded as `%25`: https://twitter.com/%25

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I know it's possible to escape the character using PHP or otherwise, but I need a way to prevent a 400 error when the user types a % directly into the URL by mistake, such as this: http://twitter.com/somepage%

Comment: a single `%` is not valid in a URL, this is a bad request. The server has no choice other than returning an error 400 - bad request. You can't avoid someone to type anything in his URL bar. The best you can do is to change the error 400 page (which can be a php script).

Comment: I am running into this problem as well, with 3rd party clients sending in URLs with %'s in them. Yes, I know they are not properly escaped and should not send them to us in that way, but how can we handle the URLs anyway (essentially I'd like Apache to rewrite the URL with proper escaping before it hits my server code)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making two things. Using the apache configuration i directed this error to my 400.shtml document. Second thing was in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule 400.shtml 404.shtml [L]
```

You can play with those two and use your serverside script to get this error handled instead just 404.shtml.

Cheers.