# Rewrite a url containing percent signs with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

My site needs to take what is essentially a malformed url sent by another site:

http://mysite/%SAMPLE_URL_STRING%

and redirect it to a proper url using nginx. None of the rewrite rules I've tried seem to catch it, instead always returning a 400.

As the single percent sign, not describing an encoded character, is itself an unsafe character as described in the RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) I suppose it might be an insurmountable issue.

However, sample (non-functional) rewrite rules include:

```
rewrite /%SAMPLE_URL_STRING% /redirect.html permanent;
rewrite ^/\%SAMPLE_URL_STRING\%$ /redirect.html permanent;
rewrite /\%.*\% /redirect.html permanent;
```

Even venturing into UTF8:

```
rewrite (*UTF8)^\x25.*\x25$ /redirect.html permanent;
```

Is it possible that any url containing %SAMPLE_URL_STRING% cannot be redirected by nginx?

Comment: Hmm, not an nginx answer, but it looks like you could do it in php using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7076742/2343739).

Comment: did you success ? did you tried `\045` as % match ?